# Find min and max data column in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that specifies exactly what date and time each employee was in a particular office.

`EmployeeTable` looks like this:

| id | EmployeeID | DateP | TimeP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11111 | 1397/01/02 | 01:30 |
| 2 | 11111 | 1398/05/09 | 05:30 |
| 3 | 11111 | 1398/06/07 | 05:10 |
| 4 | 22222 | 1398/08/09 | 06:12 |
| 5 | 22222 | 1399/02/01 | 07:15 |
| 6 | 11111 | 1399/07/02 | 08:51 |
| 7 | 11111 | 1399/08/06 | 12:20 |
| 8 | 33333 | 1399/09/04 | 20:01 |
| 9 | 33333 | 1399/12/08 | 22:05 |
| 10 | 33333 | 1400/01/01 | 23:11 |
| 11 | 33333 | 1400/02/05 | 14:10 |
| 12 | 22222 | 1400/04/05 | 16:25 |

I want exactly select Min and Max date and time for each Employee when present in a office:

| id | EmployeeID | MinDateP | TimeMinDateP | MaxDateP | TimeMaxDateP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11111 | 1397/01/02 | 01:30 | 1398/06/07 | 05:10 |
| 2 | 22222 | 1398/08/09 | 06:12 | 1399/02/01 | 07:15 |
| 3 | 11111 | 1399/07/02 | 08:51 | 1399/08/06 | 12:20 |
| 4 | 33333 | 1399/09/04 | 20:01 | 1400/02/05 | 14:10 |
| 5 | 22222 | 1400/04/05 | 16:25 | 1400/04/05 | 16:25 |

My SQL code is:

```
with tab1 as 
(
    select * 
    from EmployeeTable
), tab2 as 
(
    select 
        t1.*,
        case when lag(t1.EmployeeID) over(order by t1.id) is null then 1
            when lag(t1.EmployeeID) over(order by t1.id) = t1.EmployeeID then 0
            else 1
       end lg
  from tab1 t1
)
, tab3 as (
select t1.*,
       sum(t1.lg) over(order by t1.id) grp
  from tab2 t1
)
select t1.EmployeeID,
       min(t1.DateP) as min,
       TimeP,
       max(t1.DateP)as max,
       TimeP
  from tab3 t1
 group by t1.EmployeeID, t1.grp
```

But above codes has error.
Can every body help me?

Comment: If you are getting an error, you need to post the error!

Comment: Why are you storing date and time in separate columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  One approach to solve this uses the difference in row numbers method:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateP, TimeP) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY DateP, TimeP) rn2
    FROM EmployeeTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID, rn1 - rn2
                                 ORDER BY DateP, TimeP) rn_first,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID, rn1 - rn2
                                 ORDER BY DateP DESC, TimeP DESC) rn_last
    FROM cte
)

SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_first = 1 THEN DateP END) AS MinDateP,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_first = 1 THEN TimeP END) AS TimeMinDateP,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_last = 1  THEN DateP END) AS MaxDateP,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_last = 1  THEN TimeP END ) AS TimeMaxDateP
FROM cte2
GROUP BY
    EmployeeID,
    rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY
    MIN(DateP),
    MIN(TimeP);
```

Note that the logic in the second CTE would be totally unnecessary if you were using a single datetime column to represent the date and time.  It is usually not beneficial to separate date and time as you are currently doing.

Comment: Hi, Many Thanks for your help. But I do not want the time to be sorted because exactly the time in the first date record and the time in the last date record are required.Can you help me?

Comment: The sample data you presented is ordered ascending by date and time.  My `ORDER BY` clause simply maintains this same ordering.

Comment: Please pay attention to the question. I want to find the output result from the main table. How can I find the time from the beginning line of the date and the time from the end line of the date?

Comment: Just to clarify, have you even tried my answer yet?

Comment: Yes sir. I'm working on your suggested code, but unfortunately it shifts TimeP column. I don't need TimeP column sorted. This means when the code finds the beginning and end date from each EmployeeID, then shows exactly the time from the line of each of them. Result of your code is :

Comment: @Bluesky I think that I fixed the problem.  Note that storing date and time in separate columns is pretty bad practice.  Don't do it, just use a single datetime or timestamp column.